# pushViewController does not cause new controller to draw view

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, draw, pushviewcontroller

Preface: I am not using *.xib files.

I instantiate a UINavigationController in a class that effectively serves as my 'rootViewController'.  This 'rootViewController' also has two UITableViewController members that are drawn on different sections of the iPad screen.  One of which is set as the root view for the navigation controller.  Let's call it tableViewControllerA.

The problem is, when I invoke pushViewController on a valid UINavigationController, I see no effect: 
[tableViewControllerA.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewControllerX animated:YES];

I've gathered from the posts I've searched today, that this push method should in turn cause the screen to redraw the top of stack controller.view.  This is not what I'm seeing.

It seemed there was a disconnect in my implementation, and it was time to reference a working example in my environment (xcode 4.0).  Assuming the canned templates would provide a working basis, I created a new navigation-based applications.  I simply modified didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: as follows.

```
    UIViewController *view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    view1.title = @"view1";
    view2.title = @"view2";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view1 animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view2 animated:YES];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];

    [view1 release];
    [view2 release];
```

I found similar results.  When I launch the simulator the screen title reads the title of whatever the self.window.rootViewController is pointing at.  With the code as is, the title of the resulting top screen reads "view1".  When I initWithRootViewController:view2, the resulting top screen reads "view2".

So please tell me I'm stupid cuz xyz...
Thanks.

Comment: Code please! I'll need how you're initiating the navigationController and how you're pushing your view.

Comment: sorry.  I'm new here.  I didn't mean to submit when I did.  See the revised post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some references and suggestions:

Simple tutorial for navigation based application:

http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-tutorial-navigation-controller.html

Here is another one to create the step by step navigation controller and adding the views:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/

and here a bit advance with navigation + tab bar controller:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningToolbarandNavigationControllers/CombiningToolbarandNavigationControllers.html

Comment: things start looking better when I call [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

I would like to avoid this if possible.  Do you know whether there's an alternative?  Or I guess the better question is what does addSubview accomplish that causes the top view to draw instead of the root view (from the navigation controllers perspective)?

Comment: in window you can only add any subview and then after that you get the full control of it. If you are not aware of then let me through some light in it: Window is a kind of container where you put some views (add subview) and use it for your custom appearance of the application. Now these views can be simple UIView, view of NavigationController,  view of TabBarController and etc. Now once you put one view in container now you have added view (navigationcontroller in your case) so go ahead and use added view.

Comment: is that to say that you can only "put one view in container" via addSubview?

Comment: What I mean to ask is, is there any other alternative to addSubview to accomplish the correct functional effect of the navigation controller?   Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by correct functional? have you gone through the link and created the application? It is fully functional examples beautifully illustrated, even if you download the code you will be able to see the fully functional code...are you saying that you need complete code in stackoverflow? come on...start doing coding instead expecting everything done by someone else.

Comment: I want to thank you for all of your feedback.  I had implemented the code.  I only want to know whether you know of a an alternative to using addSubview to achieve a functional navigation controller (one that causes the correct view to redraw as controllers are pushed/popped).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I have 2 theories:

1. Your syntax and calls are wrong when you do the push.  Use this as a model:

   ```c
   -(void)Examplemethod {
       AnotherClassViewController *viewController = [[[AnotherClassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherClassView" bundle:nil] autorelease];

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
   }
   ```
2. You are never adding the navigation controller to the view hierarchy which never adds the view either.  Take a look at [this](http://johnnytrops.com/blog/wp/2009/02/10/iphone-navigation-and-the-uinavigationcontroller/).

Comment: Is there a reason I should call initWithNibName when I'm not using nibs?